# F2PY not working on OpenSuse 42.3

Tags: python, numpy, opensuse, f2py

I'm running OpenSuse 42.3, and I have installed numpy 1.13.1 using `pip install numpy`.

I run the command:

```
f2py -c PDFF.f -m PDFF
```

I get the error:
error: file '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/f2py/src/fortranobject.c' does not exist

If I do an `ls` on that directory, there are no files in the /src directory of f2py. I had no issues when I was running on OpenSuse 13.2. We recently upgraded to 42.3.

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of pip that I was using is linked to Python3.4 by default. So all modules that I install using pip install' are added to the Python3.4 system directory. I did a `zypper install python-pip`, which added the pip module to the Python2.7 build on the system. I then ran `sudo python -m pip install --upgrade numpy`, and now the appropriate files have been added to the /src directory in the f2py utility for the Python2.7 build.